# Everything stuck on the top left corner

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I am trying to develop a TV Application with Android Studio. But every component such as Buttons, TextViews etc... stuck on the top left corner. What am i doing wrong?

I also tried to infer constraints but it doesnt solve the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res    /android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FDFBFB"
android:maxWidth="100dp"
android:maxHeight="100dp"
android:minWidth="0dp"
android:minHeight="0dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextTextPassword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="262dp"
    android:layout_height="296dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="232dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: try to remove the `app:layout_constraint` lines, this makes every thing constrained to be attached to the parent, in addition try to use `RelativeLayout` I think that it would be easier for you to make the app using it.

Comment: ConstraintLayout has a max dimensions of 100 do but your textview has dimensions of 262 dp why? You have also constrained the bottom of the textview to both the top and bottom of parent, why? What are you trying to achieve exactly with the layout so we give a detailed and complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FDFBFB"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextTextPassword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextPassword"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```